# non linear codes

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

hello everybody im taking a course in nonlinear codes next semester and in order to be prepared as best as i can im trying to solve an home exercise given to us to be done by the semesters opening. Im writing here the questions i didn't succeed, these exercises are about constant weight codes, linear cyclic codes and a bit of combinatorics

1.Let $\Phi={(C_1,C_2,...)}$ be a set of linear codes over a finite field  $F_q$, all of length $n$ and dimension $k$. assume every non zero vector $v \in F_q^n $ is contained in the same number of codes from $\Phi$. Prove that if $$\sum_{i=1}^{d-1} {{n \choose i}(q-1)^i} < \frac{q^n-1}{q^k-1}$$
then $\Phi$ contains a code with minimum distance at least $d$.

2. $n$ and $q$ are positive integers such that $\gcd(n,q)=1 $. Fix a polonymial $g(x)$, wich we shall use as a generator polynomial to constuct a cyclic code over $F_q$ of length $n$. Prove that we can pick $n$ such that the resulting cyclic code has a minimum distance at most 2, regardless of the choice of $g(x)$.

for the second question i tried to use the fact that $g(x)$ have only simple roots in their splitting field but im not sure how to connect it to a upper bound for the code

ill appreciate any help, clues or guidance
thanks

Comment: For the first problem, do you have any geometric intuition for what either of the quantities in the inequality correspond to? At least the quantity on the left-hand side has a geometrically simple meaning that I encourage you to try to think about.

Comment: the left side is the size of a ball of radius d-1 over F_q correct? for the right side i tried to look at it as portion of two field sizes but didnt succeed to advance with that

Comment: The "geometric" interpretation of the inequality is as follows. If $B$ is some set, another set $A$ is called a *packing* if $a+B \cap a'+B= \emptyset$ for all $a,a'\in A$, or equivalently $|A+B| = |A||B|$, where $+$ here is the minkowski sum/sumset. Your inequality can therefore be written as $|\mathbb{F}_q^k\setminus \{0\}| |B_0(d-1)| < |\mathbb{F}_q^n\setminus\{0\}|$ where $B_0(d-1)$ is the Hamming ball you describe. Can you rewrite this in terms of packings? And what can you say about the minimum distance of a packing of Hamming balls?

Comment: i tried to go in this way but didnt succeed to advance further than you described, i tried also to use the code anticode bound but im really not sure about what i wrote, also i tried to use the hamming ball to describe an anticode with $d_max<2(d-1)$. can you please expand your answer? also im nut sure how to use the analogy of packing wich set is $A$ and wich is $B$? in order to use it i need to define them such that the intersection will be empty

Comment: Looking more carefully, it seems that I misread the upper summation index to be $(d-1)/2$. If this were the case, the proof would follow exactly the same proof as the Hamming bound, which is what I was alluding to. Without this condition, you probably instead need to leverage the condition that "every non-zero vector is contained in the same number of codes...".

Comment: The standard argument (at least for the case of Euclidean lattices, which should be similar) is to look at fixed $v\in\mathbb{F}_q^n\setminus\{0\}$, look at $\Pr_{C_i\gets \Phi}[v\in C_i]$ where the choice of $C_i$ is uniform, and then union bound over $v$ in a suitable Hamming ball and take complements to lower bound the probability that some $C_i$ doesn't contain a "short" $v$ (which is precisely lower bounding the minimum distance). Hopefully the inequality you are given is such that this argument works, but I haven't checked.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers, i didnt understand what probability you are meaning and what it means union bound over $v$ and what complements to take in order to lower the bound' i also tried to describe the problem as a steiner system bu i dont think this is the way

Answer (score 1):

Writing up a slightly more complete (but still not complete) sketch of an answer I mentioned in the comments.

A key question you should ask yourself (and a hint towards this kind of solution) is

> Why am I given a *collection* $\Phi = (C_1,\dots, C_\ell)$ of codes, rather than a single one?

Generally, this is because you are expected to use some "probabilistic argument", meaning prove some statement of the form

$$\Pr_{C_i \gets \Phi}[C_i\text{ has minimum distance }\geq d] > 0$$
If the probability is strictly positive, at least one $C_i$ must have the property, even if you don't know which.
It's also worth mentioning the precise distribution on $\Phi$ you choose doesn't matter provided you can get the above argument to work, but when $\Phi$ is finite the uniform distribution is of course the "most obvious" choice.

Now, a key perspective in (a similar argument to this in the world of Euclidean lattices) is noticing that

> A code $C_i$ has minimum distance $\geq d$ iff $\forall v\in B_0(d-1)\setminus\{0\}$, $v\not\in C_i$.

Returning to the probability we want to lower-bound, we have that

\begin{align*}
\Pr_{C_i \gets \Phi}[C_i\text{ has minimum distance }\geq d] &= \Pr_{C_i \gets \Phi}[\forall v\in B_0(d-1)\setminus\{0\}, v\not\in C_i]\\
&= 1 - \Pr_{C_i \gets \Phi}[\exists v\in B_0(d-1)\setminus\{0\}, v\in C_i]\\
&\geq 1 - \mathsf{vol}(B_0(d-1)\setminus\{0\})\max_{v\in B_0(d-1)\setminus\{0\}}\Pr_{C_i \gets \Phi}[ v\in C_i].
\end{align*}
Here, in the first equality, we simply apply the above characterization of minimum distance.
In the second inequality, we take complements, and in the third inequality, we apply the "union bound"
$$\Pr[\exists x\in A : T(x)] \leq \sum_{x\in A}\Pr[T(x)] \leq |A|\max_{x\in A}\Pr[T(x)]$$
where $T(x)$ is an arbitrary predicate.
Technically the first inequality is the union bound, but I use the second as well so I describe it anyway.

Anyway, we are trying to lower bound our probability by $>0$ *strictly*.
It therefore suffices to show that
$$\frac{1}{\mathsf{vol}(B_0(d-1)\setminus\{0\})} > \max_{v\in B_0(d-1)\setminus\{0\}}\Pr_{C_i \gets \Phi}[ v\in C_i].$$

Establishing this bound on $\Pr_{C_i \gets \Phi}[ v\in C_i]$ is what I meant by bounding the probability that $v\in C_i$.
From the inequality you are given, it suffices to show that
$$\max_{v\in B_0(d-1)\setminus\{0\}}\Pr_{C_i \gets \Phi}[ v\in C_i] \leq \frac{q^k-1}{q^n-1} = \frac{|\mathbb{F}_q^k\setminus\{0\}|}{|\mathbb{F}_q^n\setminus\{0\}|}.$$
In particular, you have to show that the codes you have are "uniformly random" in a certain sense --- the probability they contain any non-zero point is precisely the cardinality of their non-zero points (as they are rank $k$), divided by the total number of $n$-dimensional non-zero points.

It would be quite easy to give you a collection of codes $\Phi$ for which this is false for.
Therefore, you need to show that the condition

> assume every non zero vector $v\in\mathbb{F}_q^n$ is contained in the same number of codes from $\Phi$.

implies the above "uniformly random" bound on the probability $\Pr_{C_i}[v\in C_i]$.
I haven't thought about doing this, but hopefully this gives you a foothold for the problem (as well as exposes you to the above "standard" argument to show that a code/lattice of a certain minimum distance exists).

Comment: WOW. thank you very much for your answer i really appericiate it, i would not figure it by meslf, thanks!!